# Pb with recyclerView

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with a recyclerView.I've a selection of players (arraylist), when you click on the image it changes the status of the player (selected or not selected). This is correct in Firebase, but when I scroll down and up the screen, the image is not good, I lost the right image.
I tried to add notifyDataSetChange but no result
Is there a simple solution
Thank you very much for your help
Best regards
Georges

```
 holder.imageClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String keyJoeur = "l" + la.get(position).Licence;
        if (la.get(position).Select.equals("N")){
            mDatabase.child("Joueurs").child(keyJoeur).child("Selected").setValue("Y");
            holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoknew));
            la.get(position).Select = "Y";}
        else{
            mDatabase.child("Joueurs").child(keyJoeur).child("Selected").setValue("N");
            holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valnoknew));
            la.get(position).Select = "N";}}
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing image on list-item when it is clicked. When you scroll down, this list-item get refreshed and thus loose the changed image and loads the default image that you are setting in OnBindViewHolder() function in adapter class.
Load the image according to selection status using if-else, like this :

```
    @Override  
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (la.get(position).Select.equals("N")){
            // set not-selected image
        else{
            // set selected image
        }

        // your onclick
        holder.imageClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String keyJoeur = "l" + la.get(position).Licence;
                if (la.get(position).Select.equals("N")){
                    mDatabase.child("Joueurs").child(keyJoeur).child("Selected").setValue("Y");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoknew));
                    la.get(position).Select = "Y";}
                else{
                    mDatabase.child("Joueurs").child(keyJoeur).child("Selected").setValue("N");
                    holder.imageClick.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.valnoknew));
                    la.get(position).Select = "N";
                }
            }
        }  
        
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. It's corecct